# How to set up winefish to use LuaTex

Tags: luatex, linux

I need to write a document that uses Calibri.  The internet is telling me that I need to use something called "LuaTeX" to do this.

I use WineFish, which is a lightweight TeX editor, in ubuntu.  I've apparently got LuaTeX installed on my machine somewhere, but I don't know how to use it to make a `.tex` file into a PDF, and I'd prefer to continue using Winefish's compiler, rather than dealing with the terminal.

When I added BibTeX support to winefish, I needed to add the following parameters to a new line in WineFish's "TeXbox" section of its preferences menu:

- "Pattern":  for pdfLaTeX, this is  "([^:]+):([0-9]+):(.*)"
- "File number":  for pdfLaTeX, this is "1"
- "Line number":  for pdfLaTeX, this is "2"
- "Output number":  for pdfLaTeX, this is "3"
- "Command":  for pdfLaTeX, this is `pdflatex -file-line-error-style -src-specials '%B'`
- "Save/Show":  for pdfLaTeX, this is "1"

What parameters do I put to make LuaTeX work the same way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5):

lualatex is a unicode extension of pdflatex so without knowing anything about winefish you should be able to change

```
Command": for pdfLaTeX, this is pdflatex -file-line-error-style -src-specials '%B'
```

to

```
Command": for pdfLaTeX, this is lualatex -file-line-error-style -src-specials '%B'
```

and it will use the lualatex engine instead.

You will want to use the `fontspec` package to access system fonts.